# Help Removing Last Traces of Genieo

Tags: malware

Some of that darned Genieo got on my computer. I've deleted all the files that the various places online suggest.

I can find NO trace of Genieo anywhere in my files or libraries, but with Safari and Chrome, those Genieo style ad underlines and bubbles keep appearing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you; but I figured it out. I created a Test account on the computer to see if it was a system thing or user thing; turned out to be a system thing.

I then went poking around but limited my searching to the system library, and found the offending file: it was in the LaunchAgents folder, and it was

com.vsearch.agent.plist

Put that in the Trash, rebooted, emptied the Trash, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what's online, so apologies if I'm repeating what you've read:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3230

Specifically:

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
/Library/Input Methods/
/Library/InputManagers/
/Library/ScriptingAdditions
~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
~/Library/Input Methods/
~/Library/InputManagers/
~/Library/ScriptingAdditions

This will only really resolve Safari side issues, but it's good to check, anyway. Make sure nothing dodgy shows up in Safari > Preferences > Extensions, and, in fact turn them off, quit Safari, and see if you're still having the issue.

You can also try checking Login items

If it's still showing up from there, try booting into Safe Mode (hold shift at the startup chime/first grey screen until you see the Apple logo). If the issues aren't showing up there, then we've got a non-Apple extension or startup item running normally. You can usually locate these in /Library/StartupItems, LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons. You can safely remove anything that doesn't start with com.apple (or if you see com.genieo, there you go) from here - just put them off into a folder in the desktop or rename them with .old at the end. Reboot and test. It'll break some things at first, but just put some of the files back, until everything is working again, and you don't get Genieo issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a complete guide](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-genieo/), by Thomas Reed, contributing member of the Apple Support Communities, to removing Genio Completely.